# Number of arrays with adjacent elements coprime?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers, permutations

An array of integers is called m-coprime if the following conditions are both satisfied:

- All the integers in the array are positive divisors of m.
- Each pair of adjacent elements in the array is coprime.

Let the size of the array be n.

For a given n and m, how many such arrays exist?

A similar question whether all pairs are coprime exists but this variant is expected to have a solution. he link to the question : [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777088/count-arrays-with-each-array-elements-pairwise-coprime)

**Example:**

For n = 2 and m = 6; we get 9 such arrays.

The combinations are : (1,1) ; (1,2) ; (1,3) ; (1,6) ; (2,1) ; (2,3) ; (3,1) ; (3,2) ; (6,1) ;

Could someone point out the flow in which the number of such arrays is calculated?

Comment: The only thing that matters here is the prime decomposition of $m$, or more specifically, the exponents in said decomposition. In other words, $m=12,18,20,45, 50$ and $75$ all give the same results.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for the observation. The number of such arrays is generated when the contribution for all divisors are added. Is it necessary to generate all divisors after factorizing m?

Comment: @k99731 Could you help at this? This is a varaint of the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777088/count-arrays-with-each-array-elements-pairwise-coprime

Comment: One way to rephrase the problem is, count the [walks of length $n-1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms#walk) on the graph $G$ whose nodes are (positive) divisors of $m$ and whose edges connect the coprime pairs of such divisors together with a self-loop on the divisor/node $1$.